# Why I get stuck in loading Screen after building the apk in expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

**Usually when i login either with google or Facebook in my app i get automatically redirected to the home menu that is a map but after i build and ran my app i get stuck in loading Screen every-time after i log in**

this is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AgriEdgeApp",
    "slug": "AgriEdgeApp",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "expo.AgriEdgeApp.AgriEdgeApp",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

before building :
[before building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3DOs.jpg)

after building :
[after building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CtNA.jpg)